# TS - How to get the removed and added items in an array from old and new array?

Tags: arrays, typescript

Supposed we have this

```
oldArray = [
    { id: 1, position: 'DEV OM'},
    { id: 2, position: 'Senior Developer'},
]

newArray = [
    { id: 2, position: 'Senior Developer'},
    { id: 3, position: 'Junior Developer'},
]
```

Now how can we get the removed and added items in those arrays?

```
addedItems = getAddedItems(oldArray, newArray)
removedItems = getRemovedItems(oldArray, newArray)


// Output for addedItems
[
    { id: 3, position: 'Junior Developer'}
]

// Output for removedItems
[
    { id: 1, position: 'DEV OM'}
]
```

Im using typescript/angular2 app

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you asking us to write that function for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a function to find the difference between 2 arrays:

```js
let oldArray = [
    { id: 1, position: 'DEV OM'},
    { id: 2, position: 'Senior Developer'}
]

let newArray = [
    { id: 2, position: 'Senior Developer'},
    { id: 3, position: 'Junior Developer'}
]

function difference(a,b) {
  return a.filter(itema => !b.some(itemb => itemb.id===itema.id));
}

console.log(difference(oldArray,newArray))
console.log(difference(newArray,oldArray))
```

Comment: nice.. did not know about filter/some. Was looking at lodash. You should have a changed too - just for fun of it! when position changes for id!